# Would it be possible to get different "apple-touch-icon"s per beta site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, icons

All of the favicons were changed recently for each beta site. However, the `apple-touch-icon`s remain unchanged.

I think it would be nice if they were updated too.

Why? Well, here is an example:

http://stackmobile.com/

*Not to mention those who bookmark the pages on their iPhones.*

---

**Update:** This is now complete... can someone mark this as `status-complete`?

Comment: correct, we haven't had time to do this yet. be patient please.

Comment: @Jeff: Sure. Just wanted to make sure you knew about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

The apple touch icons are now in sync with the site favicons.

Comment: Great. They look awesome.